# Can not see windows share list in linux

Tags: windows, samba, nautilus, smb, shared-folders

I have a little network in my house and I have shared a folder on Windows.
On other Windows computers I can see the list of Windows share list but none of the linux devices can do so.

when i click on 'windows shares' in **nautilus** it shows:

```
Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory
```

but surprisingly I have access to `smb://192.168.1.2/SharedFolder`

I have tested it on **fedora 23 live**, **debian 8** and **debian testing** and all are the same.

I even checked that I have open ports of 136, 137, 138 and 445.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original WannaCry malware infestation, Microsoft has moved to deprecate the old version of the Windows disk and printer sharing protocol, SMB 1.0 faster than originally planned.

Unfortunately the classic way for Windows systems to discover and browse network shares in non-Active Directory domains still used some parts of the old protocol.

[The new Windows share discovery protocol for non-AD networks, WS-Discovery,](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/discovery/1.1/os/wsdd-discovery-1.1-spec-os.html) is completely separate from the SMB protocol and Samba has not yet integrated support for it.

If your Windows systems have disabled SMB 1.0 (as is strongly recommended for security), and you are not using Active Directory, and your Linux systems have no software that can announce their available shares using the new protocol, then Windows systems won’t be able to find the Linux shares automatically but can still connect to them if the user knows the name/IP of the sharing host and the name of the share.

There are some projects designed to mitigate this issue until Samba manages to integrate the new protocol:

- https://github.com/christgau/wsdd - a Python 3 script implementation of WS-Discovery responder.
- https://github.com/Andy2244/wsdd2 and https://github.com/kochinc/wsdd2 - various versions of a C implementation, based on open-source code in Netgear ReadyNAS OS 6.

These will read Samba's configuration and will respond to WS-Discovery queries on the local network. To use these, you must allow incoming TCP connections on port 5357 and multicast (UDP) traffic on port 3702. The multicast part of the protocol uses IPv4 multicast address 239.255.255.250 and IPv6 multicast address fe02::c.

On the client side, Debian 8 may be too old to include the new browsing protocols in client-side tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your [ipcs] implicit share permissions allow guests.

EDIT: having seen your "server" system is a windows one, i would like to point out that the default behaviour of a windows client is to try to log into the server using the current credentials - if that doesn't work, it prompts the user to provide alternatives. the IPC$ share on the windows system needs to allow guest (that is, anonymous) access though, because it is the one used to obtain a list of other shared objects. so first, make sure IPC$ on the windows machine can actually be accessed anonymously.
if nothing else works, try "smbclient -L 192.168.1.2" in a terminal on your linux machine and just keep pressing enter when prompted for anything. this *should* work if everything is configured correctly, otherwise you are just in blind luck of having user accounts on windows clients configured identically to (some of) the accounts on the "server".

Comment: I added guests to the ipcs share permissions. but nothing changed.
smbclient -L 192.168.1.2 returns OK but smbtree shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by installing package `gvfs-bin`. Except for `gvfs-bin`, most of the `gvfs` packages were already installed: `gvfs`, `-common`, `-libs`, `-daemons`, and `-backends`.